# How to know the log4j version appearing in lib directory in IntelliJ IDEA Community edition 2021.1.1?

Tags: java, log4j, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

I was asked to uninstall IntelliJ IDEA from my machine because of the log4j vulnerability. The security team is looking for the log4j version installed in my machine, which from the downloaded lib, I am not able to figure out. Can someone tell me how I know about the log4j version from IntelliJ IDEA Community edition 2021.1.1.?

**Location of log 4j:**

```
/Lib folder inside the IntelliJ idea location.
```

[image]

Comment: See the official comments on this matter: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284795 (at very least for the latest versions of JetBrains products, which is 2021.3 for most of them  / yours is older so makes sense to upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Open the jar in a ZIP viewer / File Manager / Explorer and view the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.

There should be various fields which tell you the product version (it varies), one I opened has this field:

```
  Log4jReleaseVersion: A.B.C
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I opened it with "Notepad++" and it showed me version as 1.2. Thanks